# Flex/AIR Playbook, stop mouse from propagating to view behind this

Tags: apache-flex, air, mouseevent, blackberry-playbook

I have a Sprite displayed on top of my view which houses a scroller with a map in, the sprite is a menu, and I want to stop the user from swiping their finger around on the menu and having the map scroll in the background, it looks silly.

How do I go about stopping swipes over the menu from passing through the the map behind it?

I have tried setting:

```
mouseEnabled = false;
```

but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the very small amount of information given, it's hard to debug, but have you tried setting enabled=false?

Comment: Setting it on what? You have to guess, so I have to guess? :D

Comment: Ok, I set this on the scroller, which is what I assume you mean and got the desired result, I will accpet this as the answer. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works with touch interfaces, but try `mouseChildren = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you're seeing a manifestation of [this PlayBook/AIR bug](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Events-not-working-as-expected/td-p/1191973).

Comment: After reading your link, it might appear so, I happen to be running the version shown their this this bug occurs on (the latest one in the list). I didn't see a solid solution though :(

Comment: If you can run your app on AIR on the desktop, and the problem does not occur there, then I think that proves it.  There has been no solution created yet, nor a particularly good workaround. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
               mouseChildren = false;
               //useHandCursor = true;
               buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: I have, unfortunately that didn't work and disabled all button clicks.

Comment: Maybe you could put something transparent between your map and menu